# CakePHP Hash Combine group array by value

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, grouping

I have an associative array of data, from which need to group with associative array value.

```
$data = Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [App] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [user_id] => 121
            [skill] => Baking Cakes
        )
        [Project] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => P1
        )
        [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121
            [name] => Gwoo the Kungwoo
            [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
        )
    ),
    [1] => Array
    (
        [App] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [user_id] => 121
            [skill] => Baking Cakes
        )
        [Project] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [name] => P2
        )
        [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121
            [name] => Gwoo the Kungwoo
            [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
        )
    )
)
```

Is it possible to group above array using User.id using Hash utility?
Like this:

```
Array
(
    [121] = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [App] => Array
            (
                [id] => 12
                [user_id] => 121
                [skill] => Baking Cakes
            )
            [Project] => Array
            (
                [id] => 12
                [name] => P1
            )
            [User] => Array
            (
                [id] => 121
                [name] => Gwoo the Kungwoo
                [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
            )
        ),
        [1] => Array
        (
            [App] => Array
            (
                [id] => 15
                [user_id] => 121
                [skill] => Baking Cakes
            )
            [Project] => Array
            (
                [id] => 13
                [name] => P2
            )
            [User] => Array
            (
                [id] => 121
                [name] => Gwoo the Kungwoo
                [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I tried with few methods Hash::combine(), Hash::extract but couldn't achieve it.
Can someone have an idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can make this array using `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The following line will produce an array similar to what you need:

```
$result=Hash::combine($data, '{n}.App.id', '{n}','{n}.User.id');
```

With the exception that the nested numerical index holds the number stored in `App.id` instead of a sequential numerical index.

This will work if `App.id` is unique in your result set. Alternatively, you can use `Project.id` as `$keyPath`.

Reference:

- [`Hash::combine()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::combine)

Comment: You're just one step away - how to get this to use indexed instead of associative?

Answer (score 0):

To improve @Inigo Flores answer, you can get indexed instead of associative by setting the second parameter to null:

```
$result=Hash::combine($data, null, '{n}','{n}.User.id');
```